# Python 3.9 Selenium click () does not work (Vimeo)

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I tried to click the button through selenium, but the website's HTML code seems like it blocks users to do that. (I am new to python and stuffs so not sure what it is.)

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


#others
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


for i in range (1,10):
    url = 'https://vimeo.com/user22715452'
    driver.get(url)

folder = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@class='sc-bkkeKt LtbA-D']")
folder.click
```

This is my code and this is the website's html button code and Xpath

```
<button format="primary" class="sc-bkkeKt LtbA-D xh-highlight"><span class="sc-fFeiMQ iGSRsu">Load more</span><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M14.5 10.4l-3.4 3.5V2H8.9v11.9l-3.4-3.5L4 11.9l6 6.1 6-6.1z"></path></svg><div radius="50" class="sc-dkPtRN iArNot"></div></button>
//*[@id="__next"]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/section/section/section/button>
```

When I tried to with other website, it works well, but vimeo is the only website that I cannot see exact xpath. In this case, should I need to find iframe and changed to xpath?

The error:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='sc-bkkeKt LtbA-D']"}
(Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.87)

Comment: `folder.click` This _refers_ to the click function but does not _call_ it.  To call a function, you need parentheses on the end.  `folder.click()`

Comment: Oohh why did I do that. Thanks for letting me know. Even I added (), it shows error. 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='sc-bkkeKt LtbA-D']"}
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.87)

Comment: You are searching for class `sc-bkkeKt LtbA-D` but the actual class of that button is `sc-bkkeKt LtbA-D xh-highlight`.  Why didn't you also include `xh-highlight` in your search xpath?

Comment: I tried it too, but it did not work. When I used Xpath helper extension, (//button[@class="sc-bkkeKt LtbA-D xh-highlight"]) was null. So I tried (sc-bkkeKt LtbA-D)

Comment: _In this case, should I need to find iframe_ Why do you mention iframe?  Does that page have a frame?

Comment: When I looked at the posts of people with similar errors to mine, I saw information that crawling was impossible because there was an iframe. So I mentioned iframe, but the button I want does not belong to the iframe.

Comment: Why you navigate to the page 10 times with your `for`

Comment: When I fetch that url, I get this for the button: `<button class="q9bkoz-3 cGoMpm">` I wonder if the class names are randomly generated.

Comment: After that `for`, I want to load more videos and click each videos. So that was the basic steps for me :( If I was wrong, please let me know.

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh, I see. Then maybe vimeo blocks user to crawl their website.

Comment: Sorry, your idea is to navigate to that user profile and load more videos, and then load more videos and then load more videos and so on?

Comment: That for loop loads the same url ten times, which accomplishes nothing...

Comment: Thanks for sharing those information! I deleted the for loop. I will try to find the way to click the button... :) Thanks!

Comment: @HALEY You already got it into the answers, you need to wait for the button before clicking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying this:

```
# Needed libs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# We create the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# We maximize the window, because if not the page will be different
driver.maximize_window()

# We navigate to the url
url = 'https://vimeo.com/user22715452'
driver.get(url)

# We wait for the "Load more" button and click on it. We repeat this action 10 times. You can repeat it as many times as you want
for i in range(0, 10):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-bkkeKt LtbA-D']"))).click()
```

Comment: Hi again! Thanks for sharing this. I've never learned about WebDriveWait. After using your code, it works really well! I really really appreciate your help. As a beginner, there are a lot of thing to learn more... You and John helped me a lot. Your replies gave me more information. Thank you so much...